# Service Stack Authentication using YammerAuthProvider leads to a 404 error

Tags: c#, authentication, oauth, servicestack

I'm super stumped with this issue. I really, really want ServiceStack's YammerAuthProvider` to work, but it's just not agreeing with me.

I used the example for OAuth (originally Twitter, which I modified for Yammer) authentication as follows:

```
        public override void Configure(Container container)
        {
            var appSettings = new AppSettings();
            container.Register(InfusionBootstrapper.Instance.Container.Resolve<MdsRepository>());
            JsConfig.DateHandler = DateHandler.ISO8601;
            Plugins.Add(new SwaggerFeature());
            Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
                new IAuthProvider[]
                {
                    new YammerAuthProvider(appSettings)
                    {
                        RedirectUrl = "http://192.168.1.154:2223",
                        CallbackUrl = "http://192.168.1.154:2223/auth/yammer",
                        ClientId = "rwKNTVw2idIza5XShMiQw",
                        ClientSecret = "9e9X1kpJx96mA44nsBY6flCfsnyN7fgE7s9bmQVo",
                    }
                }));
            //Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

            container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
            var userRep = new InMemoryAuthRepository();
            container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(userRep);
            SetConfig(new HostConfig
            {

                DefaultContentType = MimeTypes.Json,
                DefaultRedirectPath = "/swagger-ui"
            });
        }
```

But when I test the server out on the browser, I end up with this nasty looking error:

> Handler for Request not found (404):
>
> Request.HttpMethod: GET   Request.PathInfo: /login
>   Request.QueryString:
>   redirect=http%3a%2f%2f192.168.1.154%3a2223%2fquote%2fMS
>   Request.RawUrl:
>   /login?redirect=http%3a%2f%2f192.168.1.154%3a2223%2fquote%2fMS

What am I doing wrong, or what am I missing here? Is `YammerAuthProvider` just plain buggy and not functional?

The basic OAuth sample given by the Yammer guys is less than a paragraph of code, so I don't understand how something so simple could be so hard to get working on ServiceStack...   :(

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthFeature` by convention has a default `HtmlRedirect="~/login"` which is where HTML User Agents (e.g. browsers) will be redirected to if they try to access a protected resource.

This redirect is not related to the `YammerAuthProvider`, it's just `AuthFeature` telling the user the resource it tried to access requires authentication and redirects them to the expected location of the `/login` page so they can authenticate.

You can either create a `/login.cshtml` page (and [register RazorFormat](http://razor.servicestack.net/)) containing the login for your Web App or you could change which login page the AuthFeature should redirect to when you register the `AuthFeature` plugin, e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[]
    {
        new YammerAuthProvider(appSettings)
        {
            RedirectUrl = "http://192.168.1.154:2223",
            CallbackUrl = "http://192.168.1.154:2223/auth/yammer",
            ClientId = "rwKNTVw2idIza5XShMiQw",
            ClientSecret = "9e9X1kpJx96mA44nsBY6flCfsnyN7fgE7s9bmQVo",
        }
    }){ HtmlRedirect = "~/mylogin" });
```

You can avoid the redirect by setting `HtmlRedirect=null` in which case the Server just returns a `401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: This is really helpful - thanks! However, I am building a pure Fleck/SvcStack server with no web page UI. Can I redirect the user to the default Yammer login page instead? I guess I could do a few trials at this point.